# Creating MySQL JSON column using Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to use Spring Boot insert Jackson json object into MySQL 5.7+. I know MySQL 5.7+ can store Json data type, but I don't know how to create a Json column by using JPA Entity.
Here is the sample code I'm trying to implement:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
public class Example {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "json_data", nullable=false, columnDefinition = "JSON")
    private JsonNode jsonData;
}
```

I tried to put "JSON" in the columnDefinition, but the hibernate reports this type is not supported, so I want to know any available solutions to that.

Comment: I don't believe hibernate has an internal mapper to Jackson for example, I think you must map it as string then create a get method that parses it to what you want

Answer (score 0):

now you can use 
 `com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.JsonArray`  use mysql-connector-java 8+

as

```
 @Column(name = "json_data", columnDefinition = "json")
    private JsonArray jsonData;
```